# SharePoint Online - Archiving Permission Level?

Tags: sharepoint-online, archive

I tried searching but can't find what permission it is that allows for 'Archiving' functionality in SharePoint.

Basically, for example, I have 2 Lists, 1 is ACTIVE, and 1 is for ARCHIVED. What I want are users who's specific purpose is to MOVE items from ACTIVE to ARCHIVED.

I can't seem to find a specific permission for the move / level. Is it coupled with Add / Edit Items?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any specific permission to do this, they would need similar rights as to what you have on your Active list. At a minimum, users would need the Add Items permission level and delete if you wan them to be able to delete. I would make a copy of the Contribute permission level and trim away any options you don't need, then apply that permission level to the users on the Archive list and the Active list.